# AJAX/JS Syntax passing with arrays, Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, syntax-error

#### Background

I have a javascript code which passes three values dynamically into JSON for processing...  After discussing a previous problem I had with a colleague, he has proposed that the best way to pass multiple variables into JSON would be to define them as an array in javascript, and then pass the object directly into the ajax/JSON.  However, after a little trial and error coding, it appears the methodology is not being run correctly by the JSON processor.   My question is as follows, in the following two examples, are they functionally the same, and if so, then why would the syntax fail.

#### Working Code

```
/* New Syntax: */
var data_id = $(this).data('id');
var data_action = "get";
var column_toact_on = $(this).data('column');
$.ajax({
    url: 'xyz.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {id : data_id, action: data_action, column: column},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
         alert("Information Passed Correctly");},
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(textStatus);}
    });
```

#### Not Working Code

```
/* old Syntax: */
var dataObj = {};
dataObj["id"] = $(this).data('id'); 
dataObject["column"] = $(this).data('column');
dataObj["action"] = "get"; // "get" or "set"
$.ajax({
    url: 'xyz.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: dataObj,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
         alert("Information Passed Correctly");},
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(textStatus);}
    });
```

Comment: Yes, they are functionally the same, except that in the non-working example, you use dataObj AND dataObject

Comment: Why -1 Though!?  It may have been a stupid question easily overlooked, but its still a valid question imho?

Comment: Yes, I'd say its a valid question, I have posted a few of these myself, I will +1 it.

Comment: @jeff thanks! you just saved my raggedy reputation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your non-working code is not working..

```
var dataObj = {};
dataObj["id"] = $(this).data('id'); 
dataObject["column"] = $(this).data('column');
dataObj["action"] = "get";
```

You create an object, dataObj - thats fine. You assign a property on dataObject (does not exist, you mean dataObject, but the JS interpreter does not know that), which for obvious reasons wont work.

Try this instead.

```
var dataObj = {};
dataObj["id"] = $(this).data('id'); 
dataObj["column"] = $(this).data('column');
dataObj["action"] = "get";
```

Comment: Sorry, I think maybe that happened by error...  Don't think I originally had it like that... let me see.